# Drawer Layout does not work without Navigation Controller

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, drawerlayout

Why we cannot setup Drawer Layout in Android without Navigation / Nav-Controller ?
Whenever we want to set up a drawer we need a Nav Controller. Like below:

`private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout`

`private lateinit var appBarConfiguration : AppBarConfiguration`

`val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)`
`NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)`
`appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)`

However, what if an application does not have Nav_Graph / NavController.
What if the application is very simple.
In that case, how do we should setup a Drawer in our App.

**Please guide.**

**Note**: Before posting this question I did a lot of homweork and analysis, but in all documentation I saw that Drawer Layout needs NavGraph/NavController/Navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach now is to use [navigation architecture components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) in order to have a single activity in your app and multiple fragments; each screen can be represented by a fragment...This is the default for the Android studio **Navigation Drawer Activity** template.
The `NavController` is used to control the navigation between fragments in this approach

But if you wish you can use a `DrawerLayout` without using `NavController`.. but in recent Android Studio versions, there is no templates for that and you have to create it manually, and handle navigation, back stack, almost everything manually.

**Example**

This is a lightweight example that can make you kick off a bigger one.

When you select an item from the drawer, normally you can make fragment transactions in the `NavigationItemSelectedListener` but in below example I just show up a `Toast`

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Setting custom ActionBar
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        // Showing the burger button on the ActionBar
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val toggle =
            ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        // Handle navigation click events
        val navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_account -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                R.id.nav_settings -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                R.id.nav_logout -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            // Closing navigation drawer
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

            true
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

navigation_header_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Navigation drawer"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:title="My Account" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:title="Settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="Log Out" />
</menu>
```

build.gradle (Module)

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Navigation Drawer Example</string>
    <string name="open">Open</string>
    <string name="close">Close</string>
</resources>
```

styles.xml (NoActionBar theme)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```