# customized navigation drawer and custom toolbar

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar, android-navigation, drawer

I have developed a custom navigation drawer and custom toolbar. But I am unable to use the custom toolbar to display the navigation drawer menu items on all activities. DashActivity and activity_dash.xml contains the implementation of custom navigation drawer and custom toolbar. I need the same menu drawer and toolbar on other activities. How can I do??
DashActivity.java

```
public class DashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
NavigationView navigationView;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash);

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    navigationView.bringToFront();
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.dash);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.dash:
            break;
        case R.id.ptype:
            Intent intent = new Intent(DashActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

dash_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DashActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00008577"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/menu1"/>
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView> </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends DashActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

}
```

}

activity_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="136dp"
    android:text="Second Activity"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this is much easier with fragments than activities

Comment: @Zain could you help with the above code? and also share some link with fragments. Thanks

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579263/drawer-layout-does-not-work-without-navigation-controller/65585435#65585435